# Using Tor browser with a HTTPS Proxy that uses HTTPS CONNECT?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Currently, within Tor browser's proxy settings, there is an option for using an HTTPS proxy, but it does not actually encrypt (perform a TLS handshake) the initial CONNECT message between the browser and HTTPS proxy.

The same applies to Firefox and Chrome as well [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56981993/https-proxy-server-only-works-in-switchomega). However, these 2 browsers have a setting to use a proxy auto-config file (PAC), that when used with the same input when using the regular HTTPS proxy option (i.e. HTTPS <proxy_hostname_or_IP>:), achieves my desired result.

However, Tor browser does not have the option to use a PAC [[2]](https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/applications/tor-browser/-/issues/14087).

Any suggestions are appreciated!